# How to access the deployed Java apps in portal site in Cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry, s4sdk

I deployed a Java application in SAP Cloud platform cloud foundry environment. I wonder how to access this application on Portal site in cloud foundry.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks,
Sankeerth

Answer (score 1):

Bringing the Java application with a frontend into a Portal requires several steps outlined in [this blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/10/09/step-18-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-your-multi-tenant-application-in-sap-fiori-launchpad-on-sap-cloud-platform-cloud-foundry/).

On a high level, you need to:

- Create a Portal site in your Cloud Foundry space.
- Switch to the design time editor on Neo and create a tile for your application.
- Configure the routes for the Fiori Launchpad and setup the authentication and trust management.
- Deploy the launchpad to your Cloud Foundry space.

Comment: Thank you @Henning

Comment: I went through the blog and understood that if we need to have a fiori launchpad in cloud foundry, we definitely need a Neo account with the portal service. So, if a customer has a cloud foundry licensed account, Do they need to have a licensed neo account as well?

Comment: After creating the portal site in cloud foundry, I uploaded the files (xs-app.json, mtad.yaml,tentants.json) into the package deployer and clicked "Deploy" button on right corner. Then i see a error "**Package could not be deployed.
For details, see the Default Trace logs in your application cockpit.**" Can you please tell me where can i find this default trace logs?

Comment: I recommend to use the approach outlined in the blog post (section Deploy the Launchpad to Cloud Foundry): instead of using the deploy button in the package deployer, download the mtar file and upload it to the portal page on Cloud Foundry.

Answer (score 0):

First, please identify the correct SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit. For the trial landscape the link is https://account.hanatrial.ondemand.com/cockpit#/region/cf-eu10/overview.

Afterwards, select your global account and sub-account and go to spaces on the left.

In the SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit tab spaces, you select the space you have deployed to. Then you go to applications and should see an application with the name you specified during the deployment. Click on the application and you should see application details, logging output and a link to the deployed application.

The deployment parameters space and application name have to be specified during the deployment. If you use the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK Pipeline, you specify it in the [pipeline_config.yml](https://github.wdf.sap.corp/MA/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/configuration.md). If you use cf push, you specify it during [cf login](http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/login.html) and as parameter for [cf push](http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/push.html) or in the manifest.yml.

Hope that helps or did you mean the Fiori Launchpad?

Comment: Thank you for the response. My question is how to access the deployed Java application in Fiori launchpad or portal site in Cloud Foundry.